# Connecting to a Cloud Function through a VPC returns 404

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, vpc

I need to add IP Restrictions onto my Cloud Function, and before you mention it using a SA or other forms of auth are out of the question..! ;)

I am having trouble, however.

My Cloud Function is deployed all fine, and I've setup a VPC.

This VPC has one subnet, deployed in the same region (europe-west1) and has an internal IP range 10.0.0.0/28, and no external IP ranges.

There is a firewall, but I've set it to 0.0.0.0/0 to allow all requests through, and for all ports as well.

I've added a Serverless VPC access as well, connected to the subnet mentioned above.

However, when I run my curl command to trigger my Cloud Function, I am getting this back:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>404 Page not found</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Page not found</h1>
<h2>The requested URL was not found on this server.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

I'm confident its with regards to IP or something similar in the VPC setup, because as soon as I turn my Cloud Function connections to 'allow all traffic' I am able to ping it just fine.

PS: its on 'Allow internal traffic only'

Please let me know what I am doing wrong, or what steps I've missed. I would appreciate any help, devops is not my forte ;)

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Functions is not part of your VPC. VPC Firewalls have no effect.

Therefore if you want to control access, you can either access it from a service inside your VPC (`Allow internal traffic only`), such as Compute Engine, or use authorization that requires disabling `Allow internal traffic only` to allow access from the Internet.

Authorization requires an OIDC Identity Token which can be created from user and service account credentials.